# jQuery Hover não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `<button>` na página que após uma ação recebe uma nova classe, nesta nova classe preciso que no hover o texto seja alterado, porém não funciona, a nova classe parece não ser reconhecida, alguém pode por favor me ajudar?

Depois de uma ação a classe do botão altera de .see-move para .buy:

```
$('.see-movie').removeClass().addClass('buy').text('Gostou?Adquira já!');
```

Nesta nova classe ao utilizar o recurso do hover() do jQuery o texto precisa mudar:

```
$('.buy').hover(function(){
  $(this).text('Ligue 0800 123 4567')
  }, function(){
  $(this).text('Gostou?Adquira já!')
});
```

Comment: Pode nos mostrar o que tem?

Comment: Já li sim, minha pergunta não esta mal formulada.

Comment: Use o botao [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/216619/edit) @MunirBaarini

Comment: Pode postar seu código pra gente entender melhor o problema?

Comment: Vejam por favor se assim esta mais claro.

Comment: para usar css teria que colocar :after para inserir um texto no botão, porém para trocar o texto teria que usar :after:hover e isso não funciona, correto?

Comment: Agora sim, viu como apareceram respostas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Você não precisa de Javascript](http://youmightnotneedjs.com/).

Hoje em dia, o css está poderoso o bastante para tratar a grande parte dos problemas relacionados a ações de hover e toggle, o site acima fornece alguns bons exemplos que podem ocorrer no cotidiano e que não requerem mais nenhuma "programação pesada". Ainda creio que, Javascript deveria ser utilizado para tratar algum comportamento que deve ser dinâmico, não para questões visuais como a dessa pergunta. No caso, você tem um elemento com um texto inicial e, quer que esse texto seja alterado quando ocorrer o evento de `:hover`.

Você pode fazer uso de [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) (aqueles atributos que começam com `data-*`) para definir quais textos devem ser exibidos com e sem hover. E utilizando a função [`attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) é possível obter o valor desse atributo, podendo assim mudá-lo por meio do `content`.

```css
a {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/technics);
  display: block;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px
}

a::after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-text);
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}

a:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-text-hover);
  color: gold
}
```

```html
<a data-text='Ligue: 0800 123 4567'
   data-text-hover='Gostou? Adquira já!'></a>
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
$('.see-movie').toggleClass('buy').text('Gostou?Adquira já!');
```

---

```
$('.buy').hover(function() {
    $(this).text('Ligue 0800 123 4567');
}, function() {
    $(this).text('Gostou?Adquira já!');
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou Lucas.

Comment: Certeza? Porque aqui está funcionando. Da algum erro no console? Até seu código está funcionando. Tente talvez limpar o cache do navegador. Ou, testar o codigo pelo console.

Comment: Sim, já limpei o cache.

Comment: Só pra informar, a ordem dos códigos também altera o resultado. Ou seja, o código de trocar a class tem que vir antes.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o seguinte:

```
$(document).on('hover','.buy', function(){
  $(this).text('Ligue 0800 123 4567');
}, function(){
  $(this).text('Gostou?Adquira já!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Capture os eventos do mouse

Ao invés do `hover` use os eventos do mouse no nível do documento:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".buy", function() {   
  $(this).text('Ligue 0800 123 4567');
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".buy", function() {
  $(this).text('Gostou?Adquira já!');
});
```

[JSFiddle com um exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/gu5257rs/)