# Colocar texto na parte de baixo do circulo em css

Tags: css, css3

Veja como está

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso colocar o texto na parte debaixo do círculo usando css..
tenho o código aqui http://scratchpad.io/unequal-mist-4130

```
.circle{
    height: 37px;
        line-height: 37px;
        position: absolute;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 52px;
        width: 37px;
        height: 37px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 10px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

Comment: Oque? Explioque melhor isso, como está suas divs? o texto de dentro ou o de fora do circulo?

Comment: o texto de fora.. a palavra 'Teste' deve ficar alinhado com a parte debaixo do círculo.

Comment: Esse link é editado simultaneamente por todos.....

Comment: Pois é, Scratchpad.io mostra a edição de todos. A resposta está correta.. deu certo.. já vou marcar como melhor resposta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar a propriedade `line-height` na classe `.text`  e diminuir a `margin-left` da classe `.circle`

```html
 <style>
        .circle{
               height: 37px;
              line-height: 37px;
              position: absolute;
              background: white;
              border-radius: 52px;
              width: 37px;
              height: 37px;
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 10px;
              border: 2px solid black;
                margin-left: -35px;   
          }
        .texto{
            line-height: 100px;
        
        }
        </style>
        
        <div class="texto">Teste<span class="circle">1</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não tem necessidade de criar elementos extras (um elemento `<span>`, por exemplo) para isto, pode utilizar o pseudo elemento [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) para estilizar o círculo:

```css
div::before {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: attr(data-number);
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 30px
}

/* somente para mostrar os itens em "lado a lado". */
div {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div data-number='1'>teste</div>
<div data-number='2'>teste</div>
<div data-number='3'>teste</div>
```

#### Relacionada:

- [Função para contar quantidade de DIVs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212634/4808)
- [Hover utilizando *data-attributes*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216641/4808)

Comment: Renan a resposta é excelente e corretíssima, mas acredito que foge do escopo da pergunta. Se existisse um js por exemplo que manipulasse as tags <span> no código do usuário que fez a pergunta, essa resposta mataria a manipulação. (não acredito que seja o caso aqui), por isso sempre tento manter a mesma estrutura nas respostas.